# Why is Visual C++ changing the name of my method?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I have a problem with the following code:

```
class MainWindow
{
...
private:
bool CreateWindow(std::string, int, int, int, bool);
...
}
```

and

```
bool MainWindow::CreateWindow(std::string title, int width, int height, 
int bits, bool fullscreen)
{
...
```

Visual Studio highlights the method definition with the following error:

```
int reateWindow(std::string title, int width, int height, int bits, bool fullscreen)
Error: class "MainWindow" has no member called "CreateWindowExW"
```

and the compiler outputs the following:

```
warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'CreateWindowW'
error C2039: 'CreateWindowExW' : is not a member of 'MainWindow'
```

I noticed that if I change the method name to something else, that does not begin with a capital C, the error goes away. I'm new to Windows development. What gives?

Comment: TL;DR: because there's a macro with the same name.

Comment: Stupid Windows macros.

Comment: try to avoid class and function name that windows already use it will prevent other pre processor substitution and link issues.

Comment: Don't use "windows.h" in your headers. You're just spilling that macro stuff all over your code. Contain that desease into a .cpp or two.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is simply because `CreateWindow` is a macro created by Microsoft...
It is defined in `WinUser.h`.

Comment: Thanks to everybody who answered!

Comment: Don't forget to mark your question as answered to remove it from unanswered questions :-)

Comment: better acquire a rep-pimp to avoid rep-whoring ;-)